# DOM CSS selector: how to select a sibling of a parent element if the li has active class

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Please find below HTML structure. I want add class to the parent span if any of the li has active class.

```
<span class="caret menus">Test</span>
<ul class="nested">
    <li>
        <a>Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Test3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="active">Test4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i have tried with below code but only i can able to traverse till nested.

```
var selected = document.querySelector('ul li a.active');
var close = selected && selected.closest('.nested');
```

Comment: The span in your example is not a parent, but a sibling of items’s parent. And, what React has to do with your example? The code you try to use is pure, non-react JavaScript DOM code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to select the span from your structure, you could use [`.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).

```
var selected = document.querySelector('ul li a.active');
var close = selected && selected.closest('.nested').previousElementSibling;
console.log(close)// returns span element
```

Answer (score 1):

The `span` is sibling of the `ul`, not of the `a` you're getting. You need to navigate up through the HTML structure to get it:

```js
var selected = document.querySelector('ul li a.active');
var span = selected && selected.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
if (span) span.classList.add('nested');
```

```css
span.nested, li a.active {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<span class="caret menus">Blue if nested</span>
<ul class="nested">
    <li>
        <a>Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Test3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="active">Test4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or you could also get it by using another `querySelector`:

```js
var selected = document.querySelector('ul li a.active');
var span = selected && document.querySelector('span.caret');
if (span) span.classList.add('nested');
```

```css
span.nested, li a.active {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<span class="caret menus">Blue if nested</span>
<ul class="nested">
    <li>
        <a>Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Test3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="active">Test4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```